# Django responds w/ byte literal when DEBUG is True

Tags: django

I'm in the middle of migrating a Django project to Python 3 and updating several dependencies along the way.

Right now, I'm using Django 2.2.3.

After putting the code on the staging server I noticed that all responses are returned as bytestring literals:

```
b'<html>\n...'
```

This was very hard to narrow down because I first noticed it only on the staging server. Luckily I found out that this has nothing to do with NGINX nor Gunicorn but that `DEBUG=True` is actually the culprit.

The question is: what does `DEBUG=True` trigger that is messing up the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a several hour long train ride to figure out but I finally found the root cause:

Going over my settings file looking for something where processing changes drastically between `DEBUG=False` and `DEBUG=True`, [django-pipeline](https://github.com/jazzband/django-pipeline/)'s `MinifyHTMLMiddleware` caught my eye. Disabling it does help indeed.

[An issue about it](https://github.com/jazzband/django-pipeline/issues/691) has been opened back in May already, but I couldn't find it via Google. Hopefully this answer will help someone out there.